# Creating a Dynamic Form in a Aurelia View

Tags: javascript, aurelia

## Problem Overview

I have a controller with a view model which contains initially an empty array which will be used for storing 'Test Inputs'. I want to provide the user a button to add a new Test Input on the form which adds a new Test Input object to the array and displays the fields needed to edit its properties.

This works when the button is pressed for the first time (but with incorrect binding) but fails to create additional form elements when pressed again.

## The Controller with View Model

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import 'fetch';
import toastr from 'toastr';

@inject(HttpClient, Router)
export class create {
    constructor(http, router) {
        this.vm = {
            test: {
                id: 0,
                description: "",
                testOutput: {
                    id: 0,
                    valueType: "",
                    value: ""
                },
                testInputs: []
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The user will be able to add a Test Input to the array by pressing a button which delegates to this function:

```
addTestInput() {      
    this.vm.test.testInputs.push({
        argumentName: "",
        valueType: "",
        value: ""
    });
}
```

This function pushes to the Test Inputs array in my view model object a new testInput object.

## View

In my view I have added a repeat for binding for each object in the *TestInputs* array. The loop is intending to create the form elements for editing the properties of each Test Input object in the *TestInputs* array.

```
<p if.bind="vm.test.testInputs.length === 0">This test has no inputs. Click the button below to add one.</p>
                <template if.bind="vm.test.testInputs.length > 0" repeat.for="testInput of vm.test.testInputs">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="testInputArgumentName${$index}">Argument Name</label>
                        <input value.bind="testInput.argumentName" type="text" class="form-control" id="testInputArgumentName${$index}" placeholder="Argument Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="testInputValueType${$index}">Expected Value Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" value.bind="testInput.valueType">
                                <option repeat.for="valueType of valueTypeList" value.bind="valueType">${valueType}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="testInputValue${$index}">Expected Value</label>
                        <template if.bind="testInput.valueType === 'Boolean'">  
                            <select class="form-control" value.bind="testInput.valueType">
                                <option>true</option>
                                <option>false</option>
                            </select>
                        </template>
                        <template if.bind="testInput.valueType !== 'Boolean'">
                            <input value.bind="testInput.value" type="text" class="form-control" id="testInputValue${$index}" placeholder="Expected Value">
                        </template>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <button click.delegate="addTestInput()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Test Input</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create Test</button>
```

When I first press the *Add Test Input* button the form elements are added to the page as expected. However if I press the button again the additional from elements for the new object added to the array are not created.

Also the fields seem to be binding to the local loop variable *testInput* rather than the specific object in the array.

## Attempted Solutions

I have had a go using the suggestions at:

- [Blog Post on Dynamic Forms in Aurelia](http://blog.williamhayes.org/2015/08/dynamic-input-list-in-aurelia.html)
- [Two Way Binding Array in Aurelia](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/137)
- [Aurelia Gitter Chat Log - Help
  from jsobell](http://pastebin.com/tX3NJU8R)

But they don't seem to have worked for me. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simple. You cannot use **if** and **repeat** on the same element. Also in your case are redundant with the **p** on the first line.

Simple do this:

```
<template repeat.for="testInput of vm.test.testInputs">
    ...
</template>
```

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/250#issuecomment-161119430)